# i don't have winzip or other tools to compress . I want to use compress with forfiles command in batch file . How to use it and rename . I

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I want to compress log files on my prod server but i do not have winzip and pther tools . only compress command is working 
I tried using it with forfiles but the zip file created in throwing error. Can anyone suggest the exact syntax.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser. See http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili

Answer (score 0):

If you have compress, then, according to its documentation, you should be able to creata a zip file by using the following syntax:

```
compress -Z file.txt file.zip
```